# How to install JxBrowser into intellij/android studio manually for flutter development?

Tags: android-studio, flutter, intellij-idea, jxbrowser

By updating flutter plugin to version `51.0.2`, there is a message to install **JxBrowser**:

[image]

And integrated flutter inspector has an error that says we've to install it in term of using integrated flutter inspector. I've downloaded JxBrowser file, how can I install it manually with downloaded file (for mac)?

Answer (score 2):

This message is to comply with licensing requirements of LGPL, to offer an alternative to NOT use Chromium, which is the default of JxBrowser. JxBrowser itself should be automatically installed with this version of the plugin.

It sounds like you're seeing an error while using the Flutter inspector though? There is an option in Preferences > Languages & Frameworks > Flutter to turn off the embedded browser that uses JxBrowser if the installation failed (Uncheck "Enable embedding Devtools in the Flutter inspector window"). Feel free to post more details about your issue in the repo: https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues